# Global or Closure?

Tags: javascript, closures

[image: Console Image]

As per my understanding variable 'a' is a global variable. But when I check this in Chrome console, I find variable 'a' as a closure. Why?

```
var a = 5;
function abc()
{
 var b = 4;
 return a*b;
}
console.dir(abc);
```

Comment: In general when a function has access to the global variable closure is formed.

Comment: My chrome console shows `a` as a property of `window` if I run this code. If I wrap it in a function it shows it as a closure. Both seem like expected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it shows in Chrome but not in Mozilla.

First you need to understand lexical scoping in JavaScript. It means that the inner functions have access to the variables and other resources of their parent scope. Here the parent scope is global scope.

This is how the function adds a variable defined outside the function, inside it using closure. In order to execute the function, it will look for the variables it need. Variable 'a' in not defined inside so it will look at scope outside the function till it finds it.

This is a closure.

Comment: OP seems to have `a` closed over by `window.onload`.

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr:** Every function is technically a closure in JavaScript.

The **global environment** is nothing special in this regard (it is special in other ways). It is simply the first environment that gets created and as such sits at the end of every "environment chain". I.e. every environment created during the runtime of a program is created "inside" the global/first/top environment and thus available to all.

See below for more information about how environments and functions are related.

---

**What is a closure?**

A closure is a function that can access and resolve *free variables*. These are variables that are not parameters of the function and not defined in the function itself.
`a` is a free variable in your example.

**How do functions resolve free variables in JavaScript?**

You can imagine an environment/scope to be a table or object that associates a value with a label. For example, the environment that contains

```
var a = 42;
```

may look like

```
+--------+
| a | 42 |
+--------+
```

Now, when you *define* a function, it gets a reference to the environment (i.e. this label->value association) it was created in. The environment containing

```
var a = 42;
function foo(bar) {
  console.log(a);
}
```

will look like

```
+--------+                               
|a   | 42|         +----------------+    
|foo |  -+---------> FunctionObject |    
+--------+         +----------------+    
     ^             |name    | "foo" |    
     |             |[[env]] |    ---+ -+
     |             +----------------+  |
     |                                 |
     +---------------------------------+
```

Now when `foo` is **execute**, a new environment is created, whose **parent environment** is the environment the function was created in. I.e. when `foo(21)` happens, our state is:

```
+-----------------+                      
|bar        | 21  |                      
|[[parent]] |  ---+--+                   
+-----------------+  |                   
                     |                   
     +---------------+                   
     |                                  
     v                                  
+--------+                               
|a   | 42|         +----------------+    
|foo |  -+---------> FunctionObject |    
+--------+         +----------------+    
     ^             |name    | "foo" |    
     |             |[[env]] |    ---+--+
     |             +----------------+  |
     |                                 |
     +---------------------------------+
```

Now when we try to access `a`, it is not found in the current environment, so we look at its parent, where it is defined.

Again, the **global environment** is nothing special in this regard. It's simply the **first** environment that gets created, so every function has a reference to it (directly or indirectly in case of nested functions). That's what makes it "global".