# How are local variables kept in memory when instantiating a function?

Tags: javascript

```js
function MyFunc()
{
     var msg = 'hello';
     this.speak = function() {
         console.log(msg);
     }
}

var obj = new MyFunc();
obj.speak();
```

The weird thing about the above code is that it works. Yet 'msg' is not part of the object. So how is 'msg' kept in memory. I would more understand if I did:

```
this.msg = 'hello';
console.log(this.msg);
```

because then it's a part of the instantiated object. but how are regular variables like 'var msg' getting saved with this object?

edit: this question is not the same as closure because this is a specific use case.

Comment: How exactly is this *not* about closures‽ It is.

Comment: @deceze I'm reading through that answer and it doesn't help me. it's too broad.

Comment: Imagine JavaScript environments to be stored on the heap.

Comment: @FelixKling why use 'this' then.

Comment: Look at the section titled **An example of a closure** in the accepted answer - it's an exact copy of your code, just different variable names.

Comment: @chazsolo no it's not. I instantiated with a new keyword.

Comment: What you’re asking is how a closure works. There are 86 answers to that in the duplicate. One of those will be the right one for you. We don’t know what you want to hear exactly and there’s no use writing an 87th answer.

Comment: You mean why the function is assigned to `this.speak`? Because otherwise you couldn't call `obj.speak()`. Not sure I understand the question. Maybe you are confused about how `this` works? `this` and closures don't have anything to do with each other.

Comment: `new` is irrelevant here, the closure works the same.

Comment: Or are you asking why one would use `this.msg = ...` instead of just `var msg`?

Comment: Or are you asking why one would use `this.msg = ...` instead of just `var msg`? In production code, `speak` would be defined on the function's *prototype* and wouldn't have access to the scope of the constructor function. Also `msg` might need to be accessible on the object itself for whatever reasons. Variables and object properties are obviously two very different things.

Comment: @FelixKling ok so to get outer scope you need this. but inner scope (inside functions) you don't. but how is it stored?

Comment: `this` has nothing to do with scope (not in that way anyway). In your example, `this` is an object like any other. Maybe this ASCII art helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53863193/218196

Comment: @FelixKling good stuff. thank you so much.